# Need help in understanding explanation to this text completion problem

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Question:

> Kagan maintains that an infant’s reactions to its first stressful
>   experiences are part of a natural process of development, not
>   harbingers of childhood unhappiness or _________ signs of adolescent
>   anxiety.
>
> A prophetic B normal C monotonous D virtual E typical

Explanation:

> The sentence contrasts the infant’s reactions, part of a normal
>   developmental process, with future unhappiness and anxiety. The
>   missing word describes signs of adolescent anxiety as they relate to
>   the infant. Choice A is correct: “prophetic” signs, like har -
>   bingers, foretell future occurrences, and for the infant, adolescent
>   anxiety is a future occurrence. Since an infant cannot literally
>   display signs of adolescent anxiety, “normal,” “monotonous,” and
>   “typical” are all incorrect. And “virtual” is incorrect, because
>   virtual signs are not real signs, and what Kagan is denying is that
>   the infant’s reactions are not real signs of later unhappiness. Thus
>   the correct answer is prophetic (Choice A).

I feel the last line in the explanation of the above question is incorrect. I understood that what Kagan is denying is that "Infant's reactions are real signs of future unhappiness", but it states what Kagan is **denying** is that "Infant's reactions are **not** real signs of future unhappiness".

Can anyone please explain what is wrong in my understanding?

PS: I understood the reasoning behind the answer. I am only concerned regarding the last line of the question.

Comment: What "question 2".  Please don't use images for large blocks of text. Also can you write a better question title that summarises the content of the question "is this correct" doesn't tell us what the question is about.

Comment: Sorry. I made the changes.

Comment: The premise of the explanation is completely faulty. Of course an infant can display *signs* of adolescent anxiety. They can't be literally *experiencing* them, but the outward behaviour could be the same. If a robot moves its mouth into a what looks like a grin, it can be described as *displaying signs of happiness*, despite the fact that it has no actual emotions. If the objection is the interpretation of the word *signs*, that's entirely subjective—and it has no basis as an assumption on a test. (Unless there is more context than has been described.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct. The author of the explanation got tripped up by the double negation (`denying that ... are not`).